# Set custom resolution to hide Windows Taskbar

Tags: windows, display, resolution, screen-resolution

I am looking for a way to set custom resolution on Windows PC to make it artificially hide parts of the screen.
Display I am using is 55" TV connected via HDMI cable.
I already tried using CRU by ToastyX but without success.
I try to explain with picture below.

[image: What I am trying to achieve]

Any ideas? What I am doing wrong?

I tryed using CRU and playing around with resolution but that resulted only in black bars around screen.
I mostly changed parameters in Active.

[image: Parameters]

Comment: did you write those software? if not, perhaps his question better addressed to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). StackOverflow is meant for programming problems. anyway, with all that said, did you really only want to hide taskbar? didnt windows come with the option to?

Comment: I think you are right about SuperUser. Problem is that I am making PowerBi app, since it is premade Microsoft platform, there is no programming in it in that matter, and I want to make it 100% full screen without anything only visualization of data.